# Updating glue after changing width of a box

Tags: luatex, plain-tex

I need to change the width of a saved box and want it to look as if it was constructed at that width.

For example, this centers A in a 4cm wide box:

```
\hbox to 4cm{\hfil A\hfil}
```

But this centers B in the original 2cm wide box, and then adds 2cm to the right making the resulting box the desired width, but without telling the glues about it:

```
\setbox0=\hbox to 2cm{\hfil B\hfil}
\wd0=4cm
\box0
```

And this just puts the text on the left with zero-width glues:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\hfil C\hfil}
\wd0=4cm
\box0
```

Is there a way to change the width in a way that centers B and C in the adjusted boxes like A?

[image: result]

I'm not sure if this will make it easier or harder, but how do I do this in LuaTeX, because in practice I'm collecting boxes, adjusting them in Lua code and then put them back, like so:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\hfil D\hfil}%
\directlua{
  local b = node.copy(tex.box[0])
  b.width = tex.sp('4cm')
  node.write(b)
}
```

i.e. at the point where I'm handling the box it has already been typeset, which would make a solution that stores the tokens and creates a new box of the target width and typesets it again quite complicated.
I'm hoping there's a simple API call that will simply recompute this?

Comment: regarding glue and boxes in LuaTeX, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207367/2891

Comment: After `\setbox0=\hbox to 2cm{\hfil B\hfil}` you can do `\hbox to 4cm{\unhbox0}`. In the [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W4zc3.png) I added `X` at the sides of the boxes and `\hrulefill` instead of `\hfil` to see the effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\hfil C\hfil}
\setbox0=\hbox to 4cm{\unhbox0}
\box0
```

Comment: I arrived four seconds earlier. :-P

Comment: @egreg But mine's an answer

Comment: cool I didn't know about `\unhbox`. But is there a way to do this with a box object in Lua?

Comment: @pascal yes you'll just need to move the node list representing the horizontal list to the new box node. I'd have to look up the lua syntax (unlike the TeX that I could write in my sleep:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I arrived one day later. :(

Comment: @pascal You can re-box the box 0 using lua code (as you wish) and then you can do `\setbox0=\hbox to\wd0{\unhbox0}`

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, here's the Lua version, turns out `\unhbox` is simply accessing `head`, effectively discarding the old hbox, and constructing a new hbox with an exact width, just like the plain version:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\hfil D\hfil}%
\directlua{
  local b = node.copy(tex.box[0])
  b = node.hpack(b.head, tex.sp('4cm'), 'exactly')
  node.write(b)
}
```