# Change height of a box, recalculate rubber lengths

Tags: boxes, dimensions

I'm using `\setbox` and `\usebox` to define a box, measure its default dimensions and render it later. During rendering, sometimes there is more vertical space available than measured initially, and I'd like to distribute this space between paragraphs. Is this possible using only the `\mybox` box in the example below?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newbox\mybox

\begin{document}
  \setbox\mybox=\hbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{10em}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus5ex}
      First paragraph

      Second paragraph

      Third paragraph
    \end{minipage}
  }%
  %
  \usebox{\mybox}
  % How can I render the box with a specified height and distribute the paragraphs
  % according to the parskip?
\end{document}
```

[Updating glue after changing width of a box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233396/8057) seems related, but I don't see how to apply the technique shown there to change the height of a box.

Comment: You can't do it with `minipage`, you can if you say `\setbox\mybox=\vbox{...}` and then do tricks with `\unvbox`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Can I use a `\vbox` like a minipage (type in paragraphs separated by an empty line, specify the width of the box)? Then I could use `\vbox` instead of `minipage` -- but isn't a minipage just a box (internally) that can be unboxed just the same?

Comment: You should add `\@minipagerestore` at the start, so the behavior should be the same as in a minipage

Comment: @egreg: At the start of what?

Comment: `\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\@minipagerestore...}` (requires `\makeatletter`).

Answer (score 3):

After the removal of white spaces by line ends at the begin and end of the `\hbox`, the box `\mybox` is an `\hbox`, which contains a `\vtop`. Then the outer `\hbox` can be unpacked with `\unhcopy` or `\unhbox` (the latter clears the contents of the box). `\lastbox` catches the unpacked `\vtop`, which can be unpacked with `\unvcopy` and put into a new `\vtop` with the specified height:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newbox\mybox 
\newbox\tmpbox

\begin{document}
  \setbox\mybox=\hbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{10em}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus5ex}
      First paragraph

      Second paragraph

      Third paragraph
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  %
  \unhcopy\mybox
  \setbox\tmpbox=\lastbox
  \vtop to 100pt{\unvcopy\tmpbox}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This works like a charm for my application, from the first try. Many thanks!