# Centered-justified or right-justified

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I get justified text, with the last line in each paragraph centered, or justified text with the last line flush right? Is there a typographic reason why I cannot find this setting?

Comment: here are two previous questions on the subject: [How to center the last line of a paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99364/579) (r-to-l text); [Center last line of the paragraph; but I don't like small lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280017/579).

Comment: Those who are interested in non-typical paragraph shapes might be interested in two TUGboat articles, available as https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-2/tb89glister.pdf and https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-2/tb92glister.pdf

Answer (score 8):

See subsection 18.3.1 of [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf).

The solution for a centered last line is to put the following lines in your document:

```
\leftskip=0cm plus 0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus -0.5fil
\parfillskip=0cm plus 1fil
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\leftskip=0cm plus 0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus -0.5fil
\parfillskip=0cm plus 1fil

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want right alignement for the last line, change

```
\parfillskip=0cm plus 1fil
```

to

```
\parfillskip=0cm plus 0.5fil
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't have time in the next week or two to review the code you've given me, but I'll accept your answer when I do.